# Consulta como limpiar los edittext de distintos fragment desde el padre

Tags: android-studio

esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien, estoy avanzando con mi primer fragment ha sido dificil desde grabar hasta ahora de como limpiar, este es el coidgo que utiizo en el fragemnt llamado datos que corresponde al padre:

```
public class datos extends Fragment {

EditText txtsiniestro,txtregistro1,txtpoliza,txtfechadenuncia,txtfechadesignacion,txtfechainspeccion,
        txtanalista,txtliq,txtitem,txtactivo8,txtregistro,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,
        aa,ab,ac,ad,ae,af,ag,ah,ai,aj,ak,al,am,an,ao,ap,aq,ar,as,at,au,av,aw;
Button btn_grabar,btn_buscar,btn_modificar,btn_eliminar,btn_limpiar,btn_salir;
Spinner spsiniestro;
private AsyncHttpClient cliente;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
asegurado fragmentAsegurado;

public datos() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_datos, container, false);
    txtregistro = view.findViewById(R.id.txtregristro);
    txtsiniestro = view.findViewById(R.id.txtsiniestro);
    txtregistro1 = view.findViewById(R.id.txtregistro1);
    txtpoliza = view.findViewById(R.id.txtpoliza);
    txtfechadenuncia = view.findViewById(R.id.txtfechadenuncia);
    txtfechadesignacion = view.findViewById(R.id.txtfechadesignacion);
    txtfechainspeccion = view.findViewById(R.id.txtfechainspeccion);
    txtanalista = view.findViewById(R.id.txtanalista);
    txtliq = view.findViewById(R.id.txtliq);
    txtitem = view.findViewById(R.id.txtitem);
    txtactivo8 = view.findViewById(R.id.txtactivo8);
    a = view.findViewById(R.id.a);
    b = view.findViewById(R.id.b);
    c = view.findViewById(R.id.c);
    d = view.findViewById(R.id.d);
    e = view.findViewById(R.id.e);
    f = view.findViewById(R.id.f);
    g = view.findViewById(R.id.g);
    h = view.findViewById(R.id.h);
    i = view.findViewById(R.id.i);
    j = view.findViewById(R.id.j);
    k = view.findViewById(R.id.k);
    l = view.findViewById(R.id.l);
    m = view.findViewById(R.id.m);
    n = view.findViewById(R.id.n);
    o = view.findViewById(R.id.o);
    p = view.findViewById(R.id.p);
    q = view.findViewById(R.id.q);
    r = view.findViewById(R.id.r);
    s = view.findViewById(R.id.s);
    t = view.findViewById(R.id.t);
    u = view.findViewById(R.id.u);
    v = view.findViewById(R.id.v);
    w = view.findViewById(R.id.w);
    x = view.findViewById(R.id.x);
    y = view.findViewById(R.id.y);
    z = view.findViewById(R.id.z);
    aa = view.findViewById(R.id.aa);
    ab = view.findViewById(R.id.ab);
    ac = view.findViewById(R.id.ac);
    ad = view.findViewById(R.id.ad);
    ae = view.findViewById(R.id.ae);
    af = view.findViewById(R.id.af);
    ag = view.findViewById(R.id.ag);
    ah = view.findViewById(R.id.ah);
    ai = view.findViewById(R.id.ai);
    aj = view.findViewById(R.id.aj);
    ak = view.findViewById(R.id.ak);
    al = view.findViewById(R.id.al);
    am = view.findViewById(R.id.am);
    an = view.findViewById(R.id.an);
    ao = view.findViewById(R.id.ao);
    ap = view.findViewById(R.id.ap);
    aq = view.findViewById(R.id.aq);
    ar = view.findViewById(R.id.ar);
    as = view.findViewById(R.id.as);
    at = view.findViewById(R.id.at);
    au = view.findViewById(R.id.au);
    av = view.findViewById(R.id.av);
    aw = view.findViewById(R.id.aw);
    btn_grabar = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_grabar);
    btn_buscar =view.findViewById(R.id.btn_buscar);
    spsiniestro = view.findViewById(R.id.spsiniestro);
    cliente = new AsyncHttpClient();
    btn_modificar = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_modificar);
    btn_eliminar = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_eliminar);
    btn_limpiar = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_limpiar);
    btn_salir = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_salir);
    txtregistro.setEnabled(false);
    txtliq.setText("N° 2023-*-FVJ/VEH");
    txtsiniestro.requestFocus();

    ArrayList<String> seleccion = new ArrayList<>();
    seleccion.add("Seleccione");
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter (datos.super.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, seleccion);
    spsiniestro.setAdapter(adaptador);

    txtregistro1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = "http://192.168.1.89/oficina/buscar_casos4.php?ID=" + txtregistro1.getText().toString();
            JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    if (response.length() > 0) {
                        try {
                            jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(0);
                            txtsiniestro.setText(jsonObject.getString("N_Siniestro"));
                            txtregistro1.setText(jsonObject.getString("ID"));
                            txtpoliza.setText(jsonObject.getString("N_Poliza"));
                            txtfechadenuncia.setText(jsonObject.getString("Fecha_Denuncia"));
                            txtfechadesignacion.setText(jsonObject.getString("Fecha_Designacion"));
                            a.setText(jsonObject.getString("Nombre_Asegurado"));
                            b.setText(jsonObject.getString("Rut_Asegurado"));
                            c.setText(jsonObject.getString("Nombre_Conductor"));
                            d.setText(jsonObject.getString("Rut_Conductor"));
                            e.setText(jsonObject.getString("Fecha_Siniestro"));
                            f.setText(jsonObject.getString("Nombre_Tercero"));
                            g.setText(jsonObject.getString("Patente_Tercero"));
                            h.setText(jsonObject.getString("Patente_Vehiculo"));
                            txtfechainspeccion.requestFocus();
                            traspaso1();
                            traspaso();
                        } catch (JSONException e){
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Este Registro no ha sido ingresado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        txtpoliza.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error de conexión", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
            requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
        }
    });

    txtfechadenuncia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
            int day = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int month = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    datos.super.getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    txtfechadenuncia.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                    txtfechadesignacion.requestFocus();
                }
            }, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });

    txtfechadesignacion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
            int day = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int month = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    datos.super.getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    txtfechadesignacion.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                    txtfechainspeccion.requestFocus();
                    traspaso1();
                }
            }, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });

    txtfechainspeccion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
            int day = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int month = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    datos.super.getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    txtfechainspeccion.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                    txtanalista.requestFocus();
                }
            }, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });

    btn_grabar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ejecutarServicio("http://192.168.1.89/oficina/insertar_datos.php");
        }
    });

    btn_buscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            llenarSpinner();
        }
    });

    btn_modificar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            recuperar();
            recuperar1();
            recuperar2();
            recuperar3();
            modificardatos("http://192.168.1.89/oficina/editar_datos.php");
        }
    });

    btn_eliminar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            eliminardatos("http://192.168.1.89/oficina/eliminar_datos.php");
        }
    });

    btn_limpiar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clearFields();
            limpio();
            //MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
            //if (activity != null) {
            //    activity.clearAllFields();
            //}
            //Limpiardatos();
        }
    });
    return view;
}

private void limpio(){
    fragmentAsegurado = new asegurado();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.segundo, fragmentAsegurado,"asegurado").commit();
    if (fragmentAsegurado != null){
        fragmentAsegurado.clearFields();
    }
}

private void clearFields() {
    txtregistro.setText("");
    txtregistro1.setText("");
    txtsiniestro.setText("");
    txtpoliza.setText("");
    txtitem.setText("");
    txtfechadenuncia.setText("");
    txtfechadesignacion.setText("");
    txtfechainspeccion.setText("");
    txtliq.setText("");
    txtliq.setText("N° 2023-*-FVJ/VEH");
    txtanalista.setText("");
}
```

y este es el código que utilizo para el fragment del asegurado para limpiar los edittext correspondientes:

```
public void clearFields() {
    txtnombre.setText("");
    txtrut.setText("");
    txtdireccion.setText("");
    txtmail.setText("");
    txtfono.setText("");
    txtconductor.setText("");
    txtrut1.setText("");
    txtmail1.setText("");
    txtfono1.setText("");
    txtlicencia.setText("");
    txtfechacontrol.setText("");
}
```

este es a su vez el fragment del xml del asegurado:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/segundo"
android:tag="@+id/segundo"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/fondo"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:padding="5dp"
tools:context=".Controlador.asegurado">
```

y este es el problema que me arroja, no entiendo si cumple los requisitos que si son distintos de vacíos que lo realice:

```
Process: com.example.prueba, PID: 16410
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.prueba.Controlador.asegurado.clearFields(asegurado.java:261)
    at com.example.prueba.Controlador.datos.limpio(datos.java:302)
    at com.example.prueba.Controlador.datos.access$1500(datos.java:45)
    at com.example.prueba.Controlador.datos$9.onClick(datos.java:286)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7792)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16112)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1202)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7769)
    at android.view.View.access$3800(View.java:910)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30218)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16410 SIG: 9

favor de ayudarme con este problema, estuve buscando en la web y no encontré nada referente, solo se referian a los edittext que no están bien declarados, desde ya muchas gracias.

lo que hice ahora, fue lo siguiente en el mismo boton del limpiar lo siguiente:

```
btn_limpiar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clearFields();
            //limpio();
            MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
            if (activity != null) {
                activity.clearAllFields();
            }
        }
    });
```

ahora en el mismo mainactivity lo siguiente:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;
TabItem tab1,tab2,tab3,tab4,tab5;
PagerController pagerAdapter;

public void clearAllFields() {
    asegurado Asegurado = (asegurado) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("segundo");
   if (Asegurado != null) {
       Asegurado.clearFields();
   }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    tab1 = findViewById(R.id.datos);
    tab2 = findViewById(R.id.asegurado);
    tab3 = findViewById(R.id.siniestro);
    tab4 = findViewById(R.id.poliza);
    tab5 = findViewById(R.id.policial);

    pagerAdapter = new PagerController(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            if (tab.getPosition() == 0){
                pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            if (tab.getPosition() == 1){
                pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            if (tab.getPosition() == 2){
                pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            if (tab.getPosition() == 3){
                pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            if (tab.getPosition() == 4){
                pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
}
}
```

pero en el mismo clearFields lo mismo el Asegurado se encuentra null como lo puedo solucionar, ya que necesito que se limpien todos los edittext, ya que al momento de grabar, de modificar se deben limpiar los edittext, ya que se deben kostar los campos ya sean grabados o modificados, porque es tan difícil de trabajar en los fragment, llevo más de un mes en esto y siempre problema tras problema, mi humilde comentario sin enojarse por favor es el comentario de una persona que quiere aprender solamente.

Answer (score 0):

El problema por el cual obtienes el error:

> NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
> object reference

Es que estás tratando de acceder a métodos de vistas que no se encuentra en el `Fragment` que tienes cargado actualmente, si lo que deseas es:

"como limpiar los edittext de distintos fragment desde el padre"

**Solo debes "limpiar" los `EditText` que se encuentran en tu `Fragment` actual y no es necesario tratar de limpiar los `EditText` que se encuentran otros `Fragment` que no se encuentran cargados**, ya que de forma predeterminada estos deberían estar vacíos.

Answer (score 0):

amigos del foro y a @Jorgesys, lo solucione en parte, les comento lo que hice en el fragment padre denominados datos, lo hice así, en el xml lo siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/primero"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:padding="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/fondo"
tools:context=".Controlador.datos">
```

de aquí en adenalte los elementos y vistas del fragment, posterirmente en el java del fragment padre (datos), realice ,lo siguiente:

```
btn_limpiar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clearFields();
            limpio();
            //MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
            //if (activity != null) {
            //    activity.clearAllFields();
            //}
        }
    });
    return view;
}

private void limpio(){
    fragmentAsegurado = new asegurado();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.primero, fragmentAsegurado,"asegurado").commit();
    if (fragmentAsegurado != null){
        fragmentAsegurado.clearFields();
    }
}

private void clearFields() {
    txtregistro.setText("");
    txtregistro1.setText("");
    txtsiniestro.setText("");
    txtsiniestro.setEnabled(true);
    txtpoliza.setText("");
    txtitem.setText("");
    txtfechadenuncia.setText("");
    txtfechadesignacion.setText("");
    txtfechainspeccion.setText("");
    txtliq.setText("");
    txtliq.setText("N° 2023-*-FVJ/VEH");
    txtanalista.setText("");
}
```

posteriormente me dirijo al segundo fragment, en el xml lo siguiente:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/segundo"
android:tag="@+id/segundo"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/fondo"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:padding="5dp"
tools:context=".Controlador.asegurado">
```

de aquí en adelante los campos y otros del fragment, posteriormente me dirijo al jav del segundo fragment:

```
public void clearFields() {
    if (Asegurado != null) {
        txtnombre.setText("");
        txtrut.setText("");
        txtdireccion.setText("");
        txtmail.setText("");
        txtfono.setText("");
        txtconductor.setText("");
        txtrut1.setText("");
        txtmail1.setText("");
        txtfono1.setText("");
        txtlicencia.setText("");
        txtfechacontrol.setText("");
    }
}
```

funciona me limpia los editetxt del segundo fragment, pero con un pequeño problema el segundo fragment se monta encima del primer fragment y dejando dos veces el mismo fragamnt, es decir en el fragment de datos queda el fragment asegurado y en el segundo fragment el que corresponde el asegurado, con los datos proporcionados, me podrían ayudar y desde ya muchas gracias.